# Webmaster google tools show me duplicate content on the same page after removed the php extention

Tags: seo, google-search-console, duplicate-content

When i use the option Fetch as Google... show me the follow problems

```
duplicate content meta title
the story of....
/lifestyle/serialul-scorpion-inspirat-dintr-o-poveste-adevarata-a-lui-walter-o-brien.php
/lifestyle/serialul-scorpion-inspirat-dintr-o-poveste-adevarata-a-lui-walter-o-brien

Descoperă topul 10 a celor mai friguroase locuri din lume
/travel/descopera-top-10-care-sunt-cele-mai-friguroase-locuri-din-lume.php
/travel/descopera-top-10-care-sunt-cele-mai-friguroase-locuri-din-lume
```

this fact happened after i removed the php extention... useing the htaccess

```
#remove the php extension
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

When you change an *existing URL structure* you need to redirect the old URLs (that have probably been indexed and linked to) to the new URLs. (For the benefit of SEO and user experience.)

In your case the old URLs (with a `.php` extension) - that have been indexed - are still accessible and return the same content as the URL without the `.php` extension. So, you have *duplicate content* - two different URLs that return the same content.

Your existing directives *internally rewrite* the extensionless URL to the same URL but with a `.php` extension. Before these directives you need to *externally redirect* any requests for `.php` files to the extensionless URL. However, you need to be careful of a rewrite loop. In order to prevent a rewrite loop, you can check against `THE_REQUEST` (which only ever contains the URL of the initial request). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect old URLs to new
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ .*\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above says, for all *requested* URLs that end in `.php` that exist as an actual file then *redirect* to the same URL less the `.php` extension.

Followed by your existing directives:

```
# Rewrite new (extensionless) URLs to the actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

There is no need to escape the dot (`.`) inside a character class. Inside a character class, a dot is a literal dot. I've removed the `NC` flag which seemed to be superfluous. (I've also changed your comment... those directives don't "remove the php extension", they add it back! You have presumably already removed the `.php` extension in the links in your application, otherwise your site won't be working right now.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a far simpler solution that allows you to maintain user friendliness of your URLs. Here's the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*).php/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /? [R=301,L]
```

The idea is, any guest trying to access anything on the domain that ends in .php (regardless of the case of the extension) with or without the trailing slash will be redirected to the homepage. I use this idea on my site to make potential hackers become angry.

I then index the friendly URLs without the file extensions with google, then all is good to go. zero duplicate content issues.

Only caveat with my method is if you have numerous of php files where the URLs (one with and one without the php extension) return exactly the same content and the php files never get updated, then my method will cause guests who access the site with the php extension to start over at the home page.

Then again, if you post news on your homepage and advertise updated sections (updated urls) of your site to your guests via the homepage and they naturally visit your homepage first, then my idea would be perfect.

The point is, just make sure that when two URLs return the exact same content that at least one of these conditions is true:

1. One URL returns a redirect page which sends the user to the other URL.
2. The URL that is the duplicate copy of the page has a `<link rel="canonical" href="x">` in its HTML code. "x" is replaced with the URL of the original copy of the page.
3. The URL that is the copy has a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` in its HTML code. I tend to use this often.

Comment: Redirecting to the homepage would be bad for SEO (and "user friendliness"). The OP is getting the "duplicate content" warning because the old URLs (with a .php extension) are already indexed. If this was a _new site_ then yes, you could do something like this (although it would be better to simply serve a 404 instead). That redirect also won't work with the OPs existing code where they need to internally rewrite the request back to the `.php` file. In the case of the OP, they should be doing your stated `#1` (_canonical_ redirect) - which appears to be a contradiction to your first redirect?

Comment: so, what is best to do? if i change all the page i have and i put <link rel="canonical" href="x">  and the href="serialul-scorpion-inspirat-dintr-o-poveste-adevarata-a-lui-walter-o-brien" will be this? or with .php   . my page are still have the .php at the end.... but i dont want to see the extension

Comment: sorry for the double post... but i want to say that i have only 60 de pages, so i can put all the <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/lifestyle/pageNAME"> but without .php no???